# Animate element to a fixed position from anywhere with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

After searching and trying for a long time I can't seem to find a solution for this just yet.
What I am trying to do is animate an arrow to go to a specific location above the button that is clicked. There are 3 buttons (let's call them A, B and C), if A is clicked the arrow will go there and when C is clicked the arrow will go from A to C or when B is clicked, it will go from A to B.

A simple "left" animate function won't work since the positions and distances change every time. I have tried with the .step function and I guess it could work with that method but I can't seem to get it working the way it should. There is not much info about the .step function out there.

Closest I have came to achieve this is this, it moves to the correct position from any place the arrow is but it isn't animated, it just jumps. Here is the line of code:

```
Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${_Button1}", "click", function(sym, e) {
   sym.$("arrow").css({"-webkit-transform":"translate(11px, 201px)"})
});
```

(The weird markup is because I'm working in Adobe Edge. I'm testing all the possible ways of making HTML(5)/javascript ads and this is one of them)

Answer (score 1):

How I would make an arrow animate to a clicked button:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('#arrow').animate({
    'left': ($(this).offset().left + ($(this).outerWidth()/2)) - $('#arrow').outerWidth(),
    'top': $(this).offset().top - 20
  });
});
```

Also, make the arrow `position:absolute;` if the buttons themselves dont have `position:fixed`.

Maybe I don't understand the question completely. But I don't understand why this wouldn't work.

If you mean the btns change position continously you will need to place the animate in a `setInterval()`.

In Adobe Edge the code has to be something like this *(based on [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4301651) link)*:

```
  sym.$('#arrow').animate({
    'left': ($(this).offset().left + ($(this).outerWidth()/2)) - $('#arrow').outerWidth(),
    'top': $(this).offset().top - 20
  });
```

I never used Adobe Edge, but I could be that your error *(Javascript error in event handler! Event Type = element)* is having problems with `this` here and that there is another name to refer to the object that triggered the event.

Comment: I just tried this but I don't know if I did anything wrong or if Edge just can't handle some codes. It wouldn't let me get the offset, it returned me an error I haven't seen before and can't find on google: Javascript error in event handler! Event Type = element. This looks like an Edge only error...

Comment: I've just tested if Edge could identify the $(this) and it could just fine. $(this).offset didn't return an error either, it returned "null". $(this).offset().left does give the error I posted earlier.

Comment: What does it return with `$(this)` ?